# Нет перевода при неудачной авторизации. И зачем одна и та же строка повторяется трижды?

Tags: дефект, локализация, нет-в-transifex, авторизация

Вчера пытался зайти на ruSO, и ввёл неверный адрес почты. Мне выдало ошибку об этом, но только на английском:

[image: Скриншот проблемы]

И мне не ясен смысл троекратного повторения одной и той же фразы ("No user find with matching e-mail"), при чём под разными полями, 2 из которых к почте никак не относятся. Это чтобы точно поняли ?

**UPD**: раз строки нет в transifex, то завёл баг-репорт на MSE:

- [Transifex missing a string about automatically converting answer to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394461/transifex-missing-a-string-about-automatically-converting-answer-to-a-comment)

На вопрос повешено [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review), то есть [статус-проверка](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0). Начал конкурс на 50 баллов репутации. Надеюсь, что поможет.

Comment: Строки для перевода нет. Надо постить на MSE, чтобы строку добавили.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ хорошо, сделаю пост в ближайшее время.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ [Сделал пост на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393612/we-need-a-new-string-in-transifex-about-incorrect-e-mail)